# Trying to create a file and delete it immediately

Tags: c#, file

```
// (1) create test file and delete it again
File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty"));
File.Delete(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty"));
```

The last line throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file
>   '\\MYPC\C$_AS\RSC\testfile.empty'
>   because it is being used by another
>   process.

Why is that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`File.Create` hands you back a stream, that you haven't closed.

```
using(var file = File.Create(path)) {
   // do something with it
}
File.Delete(path);
```

should work; or easier:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]);
File.Delete(path);
```

or even just:

```
using(File.Create(path)) {}
File.Delete(path);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you created the file, you are using it until you close it - you have not done so, hence the error.

In order to close the file, you should be wrapping the creation in a `using` statement:

```
using(var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty")))
{
}
File.Delete(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try ..

```
File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty")).Dispose();
File.Delete(Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.empty"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Create` method returns a filestream which must be close before making other operations:

```
FileStream fs=File.Create( "testfile.empty");
fs.Close();
File.Delete("testfile.empty");
```